# checkbox is not checking in selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

I am trying to check checkbox using selenium IDE using click or check both.
It is not checking at all check box.
Can any one help me ?

html code for check box is :

```
<div id="iAgree" class="checkbox" style="background-position: center -62px;"><input id="iAgree" type="checkbox" name="iAgree" checked="checked"></div>
```

I have used below IDE code  :

```
<tr>
<td>check</td>
<td>id=iAgree</td>
<td></td>
```

or

```
<tr>
<td>click</td>
<td>id=iAgree</td>
<td></td>
```

Please let me know where i am wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<tr>
<td>check</td>
<td>click</td>
<td>id=iAgree</td>
<td></td>
```

or

```
<tr>
    <td>check</td>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=iAgree</td>
    <td></td>
```

I don't use IDE html code and strongly recommend to switch to java junit 4 in your ide.

Then record again.

Comment: It is not working.Giving error message as :[info] Executing: |check | click | click</td> <td>id=iAgree</td> <td> |
[error] Element click not found                                in my application after checking on check box submit button get enabled and then only we can proceed.

Comment: Try recording your test in Java JUnit4 and WebDriver, and post result please.

Answer (score 0):

Try clickAt instead of click

```
<tr>
<td>clickAt</td>
<td>id=iAgree</td>
<td></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following IDE command seems to work for your HTML example:

```
<tr>
<td>click</td>
<td>//*[@name='iAgree']</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the name=

```
<tr>
<td>click</td>
<td>name=iAgree</td>
<td></td>
<tr>`
```